# python/flask: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, flask

I am brand new to python and flask. I am trying to work my way through the flask tutorial at http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world. I have run into an error that I cannot figure out. I have exhaustively (I think) searched for a solution, but I can't find one that fits my problem. I have uninstalled and reinstalled flask. I even created a new venv and started all over again, but nothing has worked.

I'm trying to build a simple web form app. I created a form like:

```
from flask_wtf import Form  
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField  
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class LoginForm(Form):
    openid = StringField('openid', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default=False)
```

When I import LoginForm, I get the error

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

The full stacktrace is here:

```
C:\microblog\flask\Scripts\python.exe C:/microblog/run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/microblog/run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "C:\microblog\app\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "C:\microblog\app\views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .forms import LoginForm
  File "C:\microblog\app\forms.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_wtf import Form
  File "C:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .form import Form
  File "C:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .i18n import translations
  File "C:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\i18n.py", line 12, in <module>
    from flask_babel import get_locale
  File "C:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\flask_babel\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from babel import dates, numbers, support, Locale
  File "C:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\babel\dates.py", line 28, in <module>
    from babel.util import UTC, LOCALTZ
  File "C:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\babel\util.py", line 278, in <module>
    from babel import localtime
  File "C:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from babel.localtime._win32 import _get_localzone
  File "C:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\_win32.py", line 18, in <module>
    tz_names = get_global('windows_zone_mapping')
  File "C:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\babel\core.py", line 58, in get_global
    _global_data = pickle.load(fileobj)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Any help is appreciated - this is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 5):

This is build error in the babel 2.0 package on the python package index

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/babel/issues/174

To summarize, a pickled file `babel/global.dat` is included in a the package and this can't be read by python 3 because it was created by script running under python 2.

I resolved this by installing from github instead of PyPI as suggested in the github issue:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mitsuhiko/babel.git@2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Python 3.4 on Windows and I got the same exact error.

What I did to solve the problem was uninstalling the flask babel module as follows:

```
flask\Scripts\pip uninstall flask-babel
```

The babel module is still imported correctly after that:

```
import babel
```

The only problem is I don't understand the rationale behind this.

Answer (score 0):

Got this exact same problem at about the exact same time as you did - I was super excited to see a stackoverflow page on it only to see it unanswered. I *seem* to have found a fix, but I'll caveat it with the fact that I'm by no means an expert and may discover tomorrow that this broke something else.

Rooting around in core.py's dependencies, I discovered that depending on the version of python you're running, /babel/_compat.py imports either cPickle or pickle, and that's what core.py is importing as pickle.

I changed line 22 in /babel/_compat.py from

```
import cPickle as pickle
```

to

```
import pickle
```

and lo and behold everything's working.

Again, this may have broken plenty of things I'm unaware of, but from what I've read it seems like cPickle is faster so this will just sacrifice speed and shouldn't alter functionality. If you're just following the flask tutorial, I doubt that'll be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @user26379.  It got me pointed in the direction that ultimately solved the problem for me (see my response below).

Answer (score 0):

My version of /babel/_compat.py already had `import pickle`, so I decided to try uninstalling and reinstalling flask-babel. After I'd uninstalled it, I ran my app just out of curiosity - and it worked!  I wish I understood why, but I am now unblocked.